# How to introduce bi-conditional in this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

Just for context, I know that the universal set is everything and that the complement of A is just difference of the universal set and A.  A good diagram

[image]

Here is my work so far
[image]

When I first saw the world if and only if, I know that involves the bi-conditional(imply one from the other). Via my work I have shown that if A is a subset of B, the complement of B is a subset of the complement of A. To prove the bi-condition, would I have to just copy and paste/ reverse my initial proof or is there some shortcut you can take. To me, writing the whole thing out again seemed redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid "copy-past" it **iff** you note that the key-point in the proof uses *contraposition*, i.e. :

> $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p)$.

This means that in your proof you have used it to pass from :

> $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$

to :

> $\lnot (x \in B) \rightarrow \lnot (x \in A)$ i.e. $(x \notin B \rightarrow x \notin A)$.

For the other direction, when you "reverse" the steps of the first part of the proof, you have to use the other side of the bi-implication, passing from :

> $x \notin B \rightarrow x \notin A$ i.e. $\lnot (x \in B) \rightarrow \lnot (x \in A)$

to :

> $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$.

Comment: I mean i use a contraposition of the proposition - x is not a subset of B if it is not a subset of A. I use that to help prove my way towards q. So this only helps me prove one direction of the arrow. Can i just state that because i used this, you can go the other direction as well?

Comment: And just for curiosity, why did you use (p→q)↔(¬q→¬p) (bicondition and the sign for logical equivalence)? I get that any is true, you can imply the other is true.